# Memory leak Investigation

Tags: windows, debugging, memory-leaks, windbg, umdh

I am investigating memory of an application running on 32-bit Win 7, built with mixed mode (VC++ and C#.net)

I've already gone through the following steps in trying to analyze the cause for the leak:

1. enabled user mode stack trace database in GFlags
2. by using UMDH.exe i have ran the difference between to 2 snapshots and i see the highest memory allocation is

   ```
   +  243040 ( 15884374 - 15641334) 872075 allocs  BackTrace17A3C8
   +  243026 ( 872075 - 629049)    BackTrace17A3C8 allocations

   ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+00000274
   ```

   It contains only one line without any call stack. which is confusing me.

Further analysis using Windbg :

1. In Windbg, typing the following command: `!heap -stat -h 02150000` (where 2150000 is the address of the heap that has the leak) After comparing multiple dumps, I see that a memory blocks of size 1 are increasing over time and are probably the memory that is leaked.
2. typing the following command: `!heap -flt s 1` gives the UserPtr of those allocations and finally:
3. typing `!heap -p -a address` on some of those addresses always shows the following allocation call stack:

   ```
   address 0813fe08 found in
   _HEAP @ 2150000
       HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
       0813fdf0 0004 0000  [00]   0813fe08    00001 - (busy)
       76ecd84c ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x00000274
   ```

   which is matching with the UMDH analysis. And here as well I don't see call stack.

Can anyone help me pointing me a direction here ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231877/umdh-not-giving-call-stack

Comment: How many MB did you spend for the stack database?

Comment: How fast is your memory growing? Are you sure that you can exclude [other factors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42935981/480982)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas. i have set the symbols for my application and for Microsoft. i have re-tested and i still see the same call stack.  the application is kept just idle and it will leak around ~ 8 to 10 MB.

Comment: any inputs please ?